# ACR122 NFC reader does not work with libnfc ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, drivers, nfc

I just got myself a new ACR122U-A9 nfc reader that I need to set up with libnfc on ubuntu 18.10. It needs to work with libnfc because mfoc interfaces wit that (If there is a way to use mfoc without libnf, great! That solution would help me as well!) After installing libnfc 1.7.1 and doing a few hours of research I still did not get it to work. Every time I use `sudo nfc-list` and pcscd is not running it gives me the following error:

```
nfc-list uses libnfc 1.7.1
error   libnfc.driver.acr122_usb    Unable to set alternate setting on USB interface (Connection timed out)
nfc-list: ERROR: Unable to open NFC device: acr122_usb:004:005
```

If pcscd isrunning, the error reads as follows:

```
nfc-list uses libnfc 1.7.1
error   libnfc.driver.acr122_usb    Unable to set alternate setting on USB interface (Connection timed out)
nfc-list: ERROR: Unable to open NFC device: acr122_usb:004:007
nfc-list: ERROR: Unable to open NFC device: acr122_pcsc:ACS ACR122U 00 00
```

And sometimes this shows up as well:

```
nfc-list uses libnfc 1.7.1
error   libnfc.driver.acr122_usb    Unable to set alternate setting on USB interface (Connection timed out)
nfc-list: ERROR: Unable to open NFC device: acr122_usb:004:007
error   libnfc.driver.acr122_pcsc   No ACR122 firmware received, Error: 80100016
nfc-list: ERROR: Unable to open NFC device: acr122_pcsc:ACS ACR122U 00 00
```

What I read from that is:

- libnfc works
- There is some driver issue
- something blocks the reader
- that something is pcscd (accoarding to the internet)

I already did the following things:

- Blacklist `nfc` `pn533` `pn533_usb` in the file `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-libnfc.conf`
- stop the pcscd deamon
- remove the drivers stated above manually using `sudo modprobe -r <driver>`
- install the device drivers from here: https://www.acs.com.hk/en/products/3/acr122u-usb-nfc-reader/
- restart my laptop about 100 times
- pray to the nfc god

Can anyone help me out and/or tell me what I did wrong? Thank you in advance!

PS: I somehow got it to work with pcscd, but since I couldn't figure out how to make mfoc use that (if that's even possible) it's no use.

Comment: Any updates to this? I also have another ACR122U-based NFC reader that I'm trying to use on Linux, specifically Ubuntu 22. None of the NFC libraries seem to be available anymore. I've tried installing `nfctool`, `libnfc`, and even `neard` via apt and every time I get the "Unable to locate package" error. When I tried to use `pcsc`, it gets stuck at this message: `Waiting for the first reader... ` (even though my reader is connected).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixing the [libnfc driver](http://nfc-tools.org/index.php?title=Main_Page) works for this. Here [is the fix](https://github.com/jpwidera/libnfc/commit/a77a2a84971f4c588a6377b30975bbe3b15d5ab4).

To make it work - clone the libnfc driver, and then delete this paragraph, as in the commit above.
Recompile and it will work with ACR122U-A9.

Alternatively, to not to edit the code, just clone right away 
from [the GitHUB repository](https://github.com/jpwidera/libnfc/)

Comment: Actually I tried that months ago and it worked like a charm!

Comment: I deleted the paragraph and then compiled and it works. However it doesn't work when I install it. It only works with the package compiled.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently there's something special about the ACR122U that causes the Linux NFC driver to conflict with the CCID (Chip/Smart Card Interfaces) driver.

As a workaround, you can unload the NFC kernel module associated with the NFC chip on that device ([PN533](http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/302/PN533_SDS-334889.pdf)):

```bash
$ sudo rmmod pn533
```

If you get this error: `rmmod: ERROR: Module pn533 is in use by: pn533_usb`  then do:

```bash
sudo modprobe -r pn533_usb
```

Now, run `pcsc_scan` and it should identify your device:

```
Using reader plug'n play mechanism
Scanning present readers...
Waiting for the first reader... found one
Scanning present readers...
0: ACS ACR122U 00 00
 
Fri Mar 31 20:16:51 2023
 Reader 0: ACS ACR122U 00 00
  Event number: 0
  Card state: Card removed,
```

Tested this on Ubuntu 22 with my ACR122U NFC reader (USB VID: 0x072f, USB PID: 0x2200) and was able to read NFC tags.

Original source is from here: https://ludovicrousseau.blogspot.com/2013/11/linux-nfc-driver-conflicts-with-ccid.html

Answer (score -2):

i resolve this question !!!!

0. put packages, the seller sent from aliexpress.com package list (I buy ACR122U-A9 from aliexpress.com )
   apt-get install pcsc-tools
   apt-get install pcscd
   apt-get install libacsccid1
   apt-get install --reinstall libpcsclite1
1. Unpack the libnfc-1.7.1.tar archive to the root of the disk /
2. Install the libusb-dev package from the distribution repositories
3. We edit the file /libnfc-1.7.1/libnfc/drivers/acr122_usb.c, find and comment on this line, there should be line 430:

/*
res = usb_set_altinterface(data.pudh, 0);
if (res < 0) {
log_put(LOG_GROUP, LOG_CATEGORY, NFC_LOG_PRIORITY_ERROR, "Unable to set alternate setting on USB interface (%s)", _usb_strerror(res));
usb_close(data.pudh);
// we failed to use the specified device
goto free_mem;
}
*/

4. Excecute
   ./configure --prefix=/usr --sysconfdir=/etc --with-drivers=acr122_pcsc,acr122_usb,acr122s,arygon
5. Making sure the configuration is correct

Selected drivers:
acr122_pcsc...... yes
acr122_usb....... yes
acr122s.......... yes
arygon........... yes
pn53x_usb........ no
pn532_uart....... no
pn532_spi.......  no
pn532_i2c........ no

6. If everything is fine, do
   make
7. If everything is fine, do
   make install
8. We can specify an explicit path for the location of libnfc.so
   export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib
9. Editing file:

/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-libnfc.conf

should be the following, add / change

#blacklist nfc
blacklist pn533
blacklist pn533_usb

10. Excecute

modprobe nfc

11. pcscd - should be off
    killall -9 pcscd
12. if there is something in the output of lsmod | grep pn
    bang, modprobe pn533_usb -r, should be empty lsmod | grep pn

Comment: What's that about packages sent from Ali Express? Please EDIT your answer to make it more clear or remove the unnecessary bits.